# How to load and run offline docker image built using docker-compose build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and have been dabbling with it for the past few days. I've managed to successfully use docker-compose for a multi-container deployment involving an app server (flask + gunicorn) and web server (nginx).

Now, I'd like to recreate the deployment on an offline machine. After doing research, it seems that most have mentioned use docker save and docker load to transfer over the base images. However, I'm wondering whether its possible to recreate the deployment from the image created by docker-compose build? Reason being I would like to skip the entire process of wheeling my python package dependencies for offline use, which I would have to do for the method starting from the base images.

I've tried to save that particular image (output of docker-compose build) and load it on the offline machine, and then tried docker run and docker-compose up but both don't seem to work. Would like to check with the community whether this method is even possible, and if so what's the right way to go about it?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the exact commands you're running, and what's the result you're getting?  Docker Compose runs _multiple_ images, and at the least you need to transfer the `docker-compose.yml` file to the remote machine; `docker save` saves individual images, but it doesn't include any instructions on how to run them and isn't aware of Compose at all.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I started with `docker-compose up` with my docker-compose.yml file on my online machine. That worked as expected. I then did `docker-compose build` which created an image with an imageID. Next was `docker save --output filename.tar <imageID>`. Then on the offline machine I loaded up `docker load --input filename.tar` and then tried to do docker-compose up from here but yeah as you pointed out, its missing the yml file. Even if I include the yml file it can't find the build path. Is there any way at all to recreate the multi-container deployment from that imageID?

Comment: No, since it's only one of the images and doesn't have any of the other information in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

Answer (score 2):

To solve my issue, I ended up making an image of each individual container post pip install, then using docker-compose.yml simply to spin them up. As David mentioned, it doesn't seem possible to spin up the container from the single image output by docker-compose build.